# fetch data from Sqlite dataase and show in recyclerview in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to get data from an SQLite DB in which I was successful to add data to it.I am using a databaseHelper class to add data and any other queries that the app may require.in Sqlite browser data is showing but dont know data is not showing in recyclerview. Ndata list is showing empty can you suggest me how to put data in Ndata list

```
public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /** Database name */
    private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";

    /** Version number of the database */
    private static int VERSION = 1;

    /** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
    public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";


    /** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
    public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";

    /** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude*/
    public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";

    /** Field 4 of the table locations, stores the zoom level of map*/
    public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";
    public static final String FIELD_LOCNAME = "loc_nametext";
    public static final String FIELD_MOBILE = "mobile";

    /** A constant, stores the the table name */
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";

    /** An instance variable for SQLiteDatabase */
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_LocName = "ALTER TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + FIELD_LOCNAME + " string;";
    private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_Mobile = "ALTER TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + FIELD_MOBILE + " Interger;";

    /** Constructor */
    public  LocationsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
        this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /** This is a callback method, invoked when the method getReadableDatabase() / getWritableDatabase() is called
     * provided the database does not exists
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                FIELD_LNG + " varchar , " +
                FIELD_LAT + " varchar , " +
//                FIELD_LOCNAME + " text , " +
//                FIELD_MOBILE + " integer , " +
                FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +

                " ) ";

        db.execSQL(sql);

        //uninstall ok
        //add data no what happend dont know any errors no
    }

    /** Inserts a new location to the table locations */
    public long insertData(ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        return rowID;

    }

    /** Deletes all locations from the table */
    public int del(){
        int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);
        return cnt;
    }

    /** Returns all the locations from the table */
    public Cursor getAllLocations(){
        mDB = getReadableDatabase();
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM } , null, null, null, null, null);
    }
//
public Cursor getAllResearch() {

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM locations";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.d("asddddd","student data"+ cursor);



    // looping through all rows and adding to list


   // Log.d("asddddd","student data"+ researchList.toString());

    // return research list
    return cursor;
}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_LocName);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_Mobile);


    }
    public ArrayList<MyListData> listContacts(){
        String sql = "select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<MyListData> storeContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String lat = cursor.getString(1);
                String lan = cursor.getString(2);
                String locname = cursor.getString(2);

                storeContacts.add(new MyListData(id, lat, lan,locname));
                Log.d("xxxxasasad", "listContacts: "+storeContacts);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeContacts;
    }

    public  void insertLocation(String lat,String lon,String mobile,String locationName,String zoom){

        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("lat",lat);
        contentValues.put("lng",lon);
        contentValues.put("zom",zoom);

        contentValues.put("mobile",mobile);
        contentValues.put("loc_nametext",locationName);
        mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,contentValues);
    }

}






This is adapter class this is worked fine



public class GetDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GetDataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private LocationsDB mDatabase;

    private List<MyListData> NData;
    public GetDataAdapter(Context context, List<MyListData> NData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.NData = NData;
        mDatabase = new LocationsDB(context);



    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView LatValue, LangValue,LocNameDetails;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            LatValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LatValue);

            LangValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LangValue);

            LocNameDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LocNameDetails);


        }
    }


    public GetDataAdapter(List<MyListData> NData) {
        this.NData = NData;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())

                .inflate(R.layout.getdb, parent, false);
        context = itemView.getContext();



        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.LatValue.setText(NData.get(position).getLat());
        holder.LangValue.setText(NData.get(position).getLang());
        holder.LocNameDetails.setText(NData.get(position).getLocName());

        //NotifiMadel MODEL = NData.get(position);
      //  holder.Header.setText(NData.get(position).getResponseMessage());
        //holder.Header.setTypeface(Custum_Typeface.load_SegoeuiB_Fonts(context));

        // holder.SubHeader.setText(NData.get(position).getSubHeader());
        //holder.Nimg.setImageResource(NData.get(position).getNImg());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return NData.size();
    }
}

Main activity:

  LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        getDB.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        getDB.setHasFixedSize(true);
        db = new LocationsDB(this);
        NData = db.listContacts();
        Log.d("ShowDatass", "onCreate: "+NData);
        getDB.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Change NData = db.listContacts(); to NData.addAll(db.listContacts()), make sure you init NDate before call addAll

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).